# how to get a page on the middle of an ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page, when loaded, an ajax call is made using jquery. It will take some 5-6 seconds to complete the request. And I want other events to happen simultaneously. My problem is : if I navigate to any other page (clicking a menu item for eg:) before completing the ajax request, it will get redirected to home page. 
Here is the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  async: true,
  mode: "abort",
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/foo/bar',
  data: params,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function (data) {
  /* do some */
  }
});
```

I think that there needs to be some additional parameters for Ajax request. But I am not sure.

Comment: What is `mode: "abort"` suppose to do? there is no such property!

Comment: What does "mode" do? It's not in the jquery ajax documentation. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: The behavior you described is not going to occur with ajax, since it is asynch and it gets canceled if you navigate away from the page. You're going to need to show us more code so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry about the 'abort'. I hope it is deprecated. But I am sure that the waiting time of this ajax call is the problem.  FYI - I am able to reload a 'div'(Ajax call) in the middle of this request.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer today. Its the parameter `global` of jQuery Ajax,, we have to set, to `false`.
Ref : http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its the ajax request thats causing problem. Instead your menu items could have been the cause of the problem. I think your menu items are created by using some divs on which you have  jQuery event 'click' is binded.
eg:

```
<a href="#some_div_id_for_secondary_menu" id="menu_item" href>Primary Menu</a>
```

On this div, you must be having some jQuery function:

```
$('#menu_item').click(function(){
   ...
   ...
});
```

If this is the case, placing above jQuery snippet in the below mentioned code snippet will solve your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

));
```

Comment: Sorry, the menu items didn't bind to any event.

Comment: I have debugged the case more, today. I found that its the global error handler, which is called to return back to home page. But I have printed the params of 'ajaxError'. 
readystatus - '4',  
jqXHR - 'error',  
ajaxSettings - 'undefined'. Since readyState is 4, I don't know how errorHandler is called !